# Add a new line after a specific word on text file using powershell script

Tags: powershell

Add the below line after the word "server {" in nginx.conf file.

```
 location /nginx-status {
 stub_status on;
 allow all;
 }
```

Using the script below adds a new line next to the word "server {" wherever that word occurs.

```
$Nginx_home = "I:\Anand\nginx-1.22.1"

$filePath = "$Nginx_home\conf\nginx.conf"

$textToAdd1 = {
     location /nginx-status {
     stub_status on;
     allow all;
     }
}

$content = Get-Content $filePath
# Replace the specific word with the word followed by a new line character
$content = $content -replace "server {", "server {`n$textToAdd1"

# Write the updated contents back to the text file
Set-Content $filePath $content
```

The nginx.conf file contains more than one word "server {". But I need to find the word first and add the below  lines to the next line.

```
 location /nginx-status {
 stub_status on;
 allow all;
 }
```

Comment: You are currently creating a _PowerShell script block_ `{…}` for `$textToAdd1`, but it should actually be a string: `$textToAdd1 = '…'` (actually use a [here-string](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/)).

Comment: Do you want to insert the extra text to **all** occurrences of `server {` or just the first one? Use `Get-Content $filePath -Raw` to receive the whole content in a single multiline string.

Comment: I want add Just  first one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ForEach-Object` to inspect each line as it passes through the pipeline, add the extra content after the line you're looking for:

```
$Nginx_home = "I:\Anand\nginx-1.22.1"

$filePath = "$Nginx_home\conf\nginx.conf"

$textToAdd1 = @'
     location /nginx-status {
     stub_status on;
     allow all;
     }
'@

$content = Get-Content $filePath

$content |ForEach-Object {
  # pass line downstream
  $_
  if ($_ -match '^\s*server\s+\{\s*$'){
    # output the extra stuff if this was the line
    $textToAdd1
  }
} |Set-Content $filePath -Force
```

Comment: That content is included wherever the word "server {" appears.

Comment: @anandarc Correct, is that not what you intended?

Comment: Only the first word "server {" is uncommented, all other "server {" words are commented in nginx.conf file

Comment: @anandarc Then change the regex pattern to only match non-commented `server {` lines (I've updated the answer) :)

Comment: R.jessan right .

Comment: @anandarc You're most welcome! Please consider marking my answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `switch` for this and keep track if you have already inserted the new text in order to only do that once:

```
$Nginx_home = "I:\Anand\nginx-1.22.1"
$filePath = "$Nginx_home\conf\nginx.conf"
# a Here-String for the added text
$textToAdd1 = @'
     location /nginx-status {
       stub_status on;
       allow all;
     }
'@

$added = $false
$newContent = switch -Regex -File $filePath {
    '^\s*server\s+{' {
        $_               # output this line
        if (!$added) {
            $textToAdd1  # output the text to insert
            $added = $true
        }
    }
    default { $_ }
}

# Write the updated contents back to the text file
$newContent | Set-Content -Path $filePath
```